# My command isn't running but why does it work in cmd and not in VS?

Tags: c++, ssh, cmd

I am trying to write some C++ code to execute cmd commands but even though i tested the commands in cmd and they work just fine, my VS code doesn't work. Here is the part that isn't working:

```
system("ssh-keygen -t ecdsa 521 -C \"ECDSA 521 bit Keys\"");
```

My console shows me that the command is not recognised, but it should be. Can anybody help me?

'ssh-keygen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I am using Windows at the moment but i haven't found another alternative to creating these ecdsa keys other than running this command in cmd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'ssh-keygen' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

is an error generated from Command prompt itself. I suspect you're using powershell when it work, so please try:

```
system("powershell \"ssh-keygen -t ecdsa 521 -C \"ECDSA 521 bit Keys\"\"");
```

Comment: It doesn't actually work. It opens powershell but at the path where my console application is, and doesn't execute the command.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply. I don't know if you've found a solution yet, but I updated my answer. Please see if this helps